# ACPI: SPCR: Unexpected SPCR Access Width Error on Boot

Tags: dual-boot

I am using a dual boot on my Dell Inspiron laptop along with Windows 10. It's been about a month since I started using Ubuntu.
This is the second time I am getting this error on bootup.
Kindly help me to troubleshoot this problem so that it doesn't occur another time.
Here is the error message :

```
ACPI: SPCR: Unexpected SPCR Access Width Error on Boot
```

Regards.
Bharath

Comment: In Ubuntu, in `terminal`, do `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`, and tell me the exact model # computer you have.

Comment: Thank You for a prompt reply. I am using a Dell Inspiron N4010 with an i3 processor. This was purchased in 2010.

Comment: You didn't show me the output of the dmidecode command.

Comment: Hi, My HDD crashed so can't get anything i guess. Thank You for your support & help.

Comment: Can you boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB?

Comment: Yes i have the bootable usb drive for Ubuntu, pls suggest steps what needs to be done

Comment: Boot to the Ubuntu Live USB, open `Disks`, select your HDD, go to "hamburger" icon, select SMART Data & Tests, open SMART Data window, take screenshot(s), note that the data window is scrollable, so be sure to get it all. Edit those screenshots into your question, or put them on imgur.com.

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry i am unable to find the 'Disks' option once i boot frm the bootable pendrive. I don't have much knowledge about it but what i did do is, reload Ubuntu on the HDD. It did boot once & once i restarted the OS, it gave me the same error as above. A fren of mine was able to recover Windows atleast & told me that the Hard drive did not crash completely thou'.

Comment: What i intend to do is, remove this HDD frm my laptop & retain it as external drive & shall wipeout Ubuntu frm this Drive. I will buy a new Samsung SSD drive & load Ubuntu on it & use it as the primary HDD without Windows on it.                   Thanks for all the Help & Support, Appreciate it :) :)

Comment: `Disks` is an application, and can be started like any other application using the SUPER key. Same with the `terminal` application. If you start `terminal` you could give me the output of the `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` command from my first comment. Once you start `Disks` you can get me the SMART Data window screenshots.

Comment: For anyone landing here, take a look at https://community.hpe.com/t5/proliant-servers-ml-dl-sl/ml350-g9-bios-has-corrupted-hw-pmu-resources-msr-38d-is-330/m-p/6831422/highlight/true#M152674 This is for an HP microserver, but the information may be useful - it seems like an erroneous error due to conflict with linux and bios using some counter... Hope this helps.