# Black screen (with errors) after updating Ubuntu from 20.04 to 22.04, but SSH works on DELL PowerEdge R820

Tags: boot, server, upgrade, ssh, 22.04

I have found similar questions but they all included a frozen system and this is not my case.

As per title, my issue is that I get a bunch of errors and then a black screen after upgrading Ubuntu from 20.04 to 22.04 on my server. This doesn't happen on a physical screen, as I use the IDRAC integrated screen viewer.

However, even though errors are showed and I get stuck with that window, I can connect via SSH just fine and everything works correctly.

Here's a screenshot of my "black" screen where i get stuck: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LB2DE.png)

I can't seem to get this sorted out, and I've tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1250194/acpi-spcr-unexpected-spcr-access-width-error-on-boot) [this](https://community.hpe.com/t5/proliant-servers-ml-dl-sl/dl380-g8-bios-has-corrupted-hw-pmu-resources-msr-38d-is-330/td-p/7072375) and [this](https://forum.proxmox.com/threads/acpi-error-stops-booting-with-latest-proxmox-update.80429/)

I can provide additional info if needed! Thank you very much.